# Проблема с запуском проекта на DJango (Не хватает модуля admin_tools)

Tags: python, django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перед этим я установил imagekit. Сделал upgrade pip и через pip2 установил модуль pillow. pip install admin-tools не работает

Comment: `pip install django-admin-tools` же

Comment: Теперь выскочила ошибка No module named sorl. И при попытке его установить: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sorl (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for sorl

Comment: Ну так устанавливайте дальше все зависимости какие надо. Если проект не ваш, то автор проекта должен был предоставить полный список зависимостей

Comment: А как ее установить?

Comment: И гуглите «django sorl» сами, почему мы должны делать это за вас

Comment: Может вы про виртуальное окружение забыли?